# Jetpack Compose Material Card border issue with padding and containerColor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material3

I'm trying to have simple `Card` with Jetpack compose and Material3, this card is supposed to have a border and a padding to avoid sticking the content to the edges of the card.

The problem is Card's `containerColor` doesn't fill the padding part, and if I move the padding to the view inside the Card then the `containerColor` exceeds the border and draws behind and after the border.

Where's the issue coming from and how can I possibly fix it?

Here's what I tried:

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize()
        .border(
            width = 2.dp,
            color = primary,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                size = 32.dp,
            )
        )
        .padding(
            horizontal = 16.dp,
            vertical = 8.dp,
        ),
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = secondaryContainer,
    ),
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                onClick = onSelected,
            )
    ) {
        RadioButton(
            selected = selected,
            onClick = null,
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                start = 8.dp,
            ),
            text = text,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: if i understand correctly you want your card to have a background color and the radio/ text Row should have some padding from the borders of the card?

Comment: use backgroundColor instead of containerColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes**

1. Extract out the `cardShape` and reuse it in a `clip` Modifier as well for the card.
2. Move the padding to the `Row`.

**Code**

```
val cardShape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 32.dp)
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .wrapContentSize() // Not usually required
        .border(
            width = 2.dp,
            color = primary,
            shape = cardShape,
        )
        .clip(cardShape),
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = secondaryContainer,
    ),
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .clickable(
                onClick = onSelected,
            )
    ) {
        RadioButton(
            selected = selected,
            onClick = null,
        )
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(
                start = 8.dp,
            ),
            text = text,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding the `clip` to the `Card` and moving the `padding` to the `Row` did the trick. Thanks!
I'm wondering why the border doesn't the do the clipping itself, if not it's not a 'border' anymore. Weird API.